# OneLogin and Azure AD SAML Request Invalid

Tags: php, xml, azure, saml, onelogin

I am trying to setup a OneLogin SAML authentication with an IDP on Azure AD in PHP and I have got the XML with all the credentials. I have little experience with these so I cannot seem to choose the right x509 cert in the XML file . When I perform the request I get this:

> Signature validation failed. SAML Response rejected
>
> invalid_response

I also have .cer files but I am not really sure how to use them...

Can you give me a hand or point me in the right direction to helpful documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Signature validation failed. SAML Response rejected"** means that the signature validation process failed.

In this case, the [x509 cert of the IdP registered config file](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/blob/master/settings_example.php#L93) is wrong and differ than the one used by the IdP.

The certificates should not be different than the one you registered at php-saml to validate the signature, that the reason for the invalidation. For example, your php saml certificate should be in your `SAMLResponse` like:

```
<ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
```

Check out issue [#216](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/issues/216) and [#434](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml/issues/434) around the similar explanation.

*Further, you can refer to [Use a SAML 2.0 Identity Provider (IdP) for Single Sign On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp) article for some more pointers for SAML setup.*

Comment: Thank you @singhh-msft. That was the exact reason, I feel so stupid of not realising this earlier but in the process the IDP didn't give me the right x509 cert... Anyways, it's all good now. At least I know I didn't lose my mind on this :D